# How to check which pins on Raspberry Pi are used

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi3, robotics

I'm trying to code a SunFounder Picar-V 2.0 with node.js and johnny-five framework. There is a one thing I can't figured out. How to check which pins servos use, which are connected with motors, etc.?

In a snippet I include I see that pins 8-10 are used, but how to check which are in mine car?

```
board.on("ready", () => {
  // Create a new `motor` hardware instance.
  const motor = new Motor({
    pins: [8, 9, 10],
    controller: "PCA9685",
    address: 0x60
  });
```

I used:

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~/SunFounder_PiCar-V $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
pi@raspberrypi:~/SunFounder_PiCar-V $
```

But I don't know how it would be usefull for me?

Comment: Maybe this is obvious and not what you're asking, but you know you can check the actual board to see which real life number pins are hooked up to which servos and motors, right?

Comment: The Picar-V uses something like Robot HATS so the servos and motors aren't connected directly to the RPi. Robot HATS is connected with Pi board all other stuff is wired with it.